# Cofiguring DHCP server on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp-server

I am trying to configure DHCP server on Ubuntu but facing some problems. Steps I have followed are given below:

**Step 1**

```
# apt-get install dhcp3-server
```

I faced following problem during installation.

```
check syslog for diagnostics. [fail]
```

**Step 2**

```
#vi /etc/default/dhcp3-server
INTERFACEs="eth1"
```

**Step 3**

```
#vi /etc/dhcp3/dhcpd.conf

option subnet-mask 255.255.255.248;
option broadcast-address 192.168.0.15;
option routers 192.168.0.9;   
dafault-lease-time 600;
 max-lease-time 7200;

subnet 192.168.0.8 netmask 255.255.255.248{
  range 192.168.0.10 192.168.0.14;    
}
```

**Step 4**

```
# /etc/init.d/dhcp3-server restart
*Stopping DHCP server dhcp3 [fail]
*Starting DHCP server dhcp3    
*check syslog for diagnostics. [fail]
```

I think I am missing something, what am I missing?

Comment: So, did you check syslog for diagnostics?  Say, `tail -f /var/log/syslog` as you start up dhcp3-server in another terminal.

Comment: what is the IP you have assigned to eth1 ?

Comment: There is a lot of conjections in this thread. There is a lot of info missing in the question: What's exact configuration of host ip/mask for interfaces eth1 and even what's others? Question's last report is `check syslog for diagnostics`, so what's dumped in this f... log!?

Answer (score 1):

You have a small s in INTERFACEs in Step 2, is that a typo here in the question, or is that the actual file on your computer?

In Step 3 you have "dafault-lease-time" which should be "default-lease-time", so that could possibly also be the problem. Other minor details, that might be more of a cosmetical thing but should still be adjusted, is that you have a space before max-lease-time and that you lack a space between the subnetmask and {, also in Step 3.

If these pointers don't solve your problem, can you paste more of your syslog file to help us help you better?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try your config like this

`dafault-lease-time 600;`
`max-lease-time 7200;`

`subnet 192.168.0.8 netmask 255.255.255.248{`
`range 192.168.0.10 192.168.0.14;`
`option broadcast-address 192.168.0.15;`
`option routers 192.168.0.9;`
`}`

Comment: netmask is already defined so an additional option subnet-mask may not be required

Answer (score -2):

edit your '/etc/network/interfaces' configuration file and add the following:

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
  address 192.168.0.9
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 192.168.0.0
  broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

restart networking and dhcp via '/etc/init.d/networking restart && /etc/init.d/isc-dhcp-server restart'

**If ETH1 is the internal LAN interface then it has to be setup on static IP first. I ran into the same problem when I was setting up DHCP service on one of our servers and after setting the internal LAN interface to static DHCP will then work.**

Comment: Can you elaborate about why you think he should make this change?